How to use XLOOKUP based on lookup values seperated by commas
I have three types of measurements I can take in each room (s/r/b), test numbers, and the room number in which they were performed.  One whole test needs a s, r, and b measurement to complete. To save time testing, sometimes a single "s" measurement may be used for multiple corresponding "r" and "b" tests (see picture).
For each Test#, I would like to use XLOOKUP() to return the room numbers associated with each measurement taken (i.e. lookup "s1" return "101", lookup "r1" return "102", lookup "s2" return 101 etc.)  The problem I am having is I am not sure how to utilize XLOOKUP() when a single "s" measurement is used for multiple tests and the test number is separated by commas.


I have tried CONCAT() and looked into TEXTSPLIT() but I would like to keep everything to a single column if possible. For example, if there are three columns for s3, s4, and s5, I am not sure how to specify which column the XLOOKUP() should pull from. Some s measurements could only be used for a single test but others could be used for a large number of tests to adjacent rooms.

You might be able to use SUMIFS and wildcards for this.

It is quite achievable please research forum, there are three possible solutions posted by three different users. And kindly don't post images its very hard for anyone to copy as text and post in excel to create a solution. Instead use Markdown_Table_Generator very easy to use. Just copy the data from excel and paste it in the said web, generate and paste here. You can do it by editing your post
